# Using UPDATE in my loop?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

```
string inserttest = "UPDATE Warranty([LenovoBaseWarrantyStartDate], [LenovoBaseWarrantyEndDate], [LenovoBaseWarrantyStatus])"
+ "VALUES (@LenovoBaseWarrantyStartDate, @LenovoBaseWarrantyEndDate, @LenovoBaseWarrantyStatus)";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(inserttest, conn1);
OleDbCommand accessCommand = conn1.CreateCommand();
accessCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT SerialNumber from Warranty");
OleDbDataReader accessReader = accessCommand.ExecuteReader();

int count = accessReader.FieldCount;
List<StoreClass> storeList = new List<StoreClass>();

while (accessReader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string result = accessReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("serialCode").Focus();
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("serialCode").InnerText = result;
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("warrantySubmit").InvokeMember("Click");

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        MessageBox.Show("Serial Number:" + " " + result);

        foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
           if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "fluid-row Borderfluid")
           {
              string record = el.InnerText;                         
              var result1 = parseString(record);

              string StartDate = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{0}", r)).ToArray());
              DateTime strStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
              string EndDate = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{1}", r)).ToArray());
              DateTime strEndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
              string Status = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{2}", r)).ToArray());
              bool strStatus = "Active" == "1" && "Expired" == "0";
              storeList.Add(new StoreClass(strStartDate, strEndDate, strStatus));

              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoBaseWarrantyStartDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = storeList[0].startDate;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoBaseWarrantyEndDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = storeList[0].endDate;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoBaseWarrantyStatus", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = storeList[0].status;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoWarrantyUpgradeStartDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = storeList[1].startDate;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoWarrantyUpgradeEndDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = storeList[1].endDate;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoWarrantyUpgradeStatus", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = storeList[1].status;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoPrioritySupportStartDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = storeList[2].startDate;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoPrioritySupportEndDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = storeList[2].endDate;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@LenovoPrioritySupportStatus", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = storeList[2].status;
              //...
           }
     //...
    }
//...
}
```

Sorry for the wall of code but its to give you an idea of what I am trying to figure out. I have this loop to retrieve data and store it into a database table. I am trying to edit my **inserttest** statement at the top so I can update the columns in the specific **Serial Number** it is currently looping through. 
Is there a way to do this? I can't do `Update Warranty ... Where SerialNumber = result` cause it only exists in the loop (unless I can and I just dont know how).

Comment: I don't know if it is your current problem but you are calling `cmd.Parameters.Add(` every single loop, the `cmd.Parameters.Add` should be outside of the loop then you you should be doing `cmd.Parameters["@Whatever"].Value = ...` inside the loop.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain hmm, I do not believe that is the issue because I tried an Inset Into and it was creating new rows while inserting my data into those columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass it in as another parameter, and add the where clause

```
WHERE SerialNumber = @result
```

Comment: `UPDATE Warranty([LenovoBaseWarrantyStartDate], [LenovoBaseWarrantyEndDate], [LenovoBaseWarrantyStatus])" + "VALUES (@LenovoBaseWarrantyStartDate, @LenovoBaseWarrantyEndDate, @LenovoBaseWarrantyStatus) Where SerialNumber = @result` Like this?

Comment: Yes, and add a parameter to your parameter list to set the value (don't forget to name the parameter "@result" just like in the SQL).

Comment: I added 'cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = result;' at the end but I am getting a syntax error :/ it looks like it should work

Comment: What is the exception description?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106629/discussion-between-kevin-and-havoux).

Comment: Sorry, I'm at work and the chat url is blocked on this network

Comment: I don't necessarily need the entire text (stack trace and all) just the description.

Comment: The exception seems to be after adding my parameters. Ill explain a little more about that. int status = 0; <-- This is at the beginning of my code

Comment: try 
{ 
status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
if (status > 0) 
MessageBox.Show("INSERT Command Executed Successfully!"); 
else 
MessageBox.Show("INSERT Command Failed!"); 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
} <-- and this is at the end of my code

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Instead of ex.ToString, use ex.Description and let me know what your messagebox says.

Comment: ^ That is the error I get back - thats why I wanted to do chat

Comment: Make sure the datatype of SerialNumber in the table in the database matches the type you are passing in the parameter.

Comment: I am working with Access 2013 - Instead of proper datatypes they have fields like. Short Text, Long Text, etc - I have SerialNumber as short text. So I assumed it was varchar. I will try to find out

Comment: Check the contents of inserttest and determine what the syntax error is. It is not an error in the code, but rather a problem with the resultant SQL. I haven't used Access in ages, so not sure I'll be much help there.

Comment: no problem I will keep looking into it to see what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I changed it a little to this! `UPDATE Warranty SET LenovoBaseWarrantyStartDate = @LenovoBaseWarrantyStartDate, LenovoBaseWarrantyEndDate = @LenovoBaseWarrantyEndDate, LenovoBaseWarrantyStatus = @LenovoBaseWarrantyStatus WHERE SerialNumber = @result;` im not getting a syntax error AND IT WORKS! HUZZAH